# What are Stackdriver Monitoring limits on the global resource?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm trying to understand if Stackdriver Monitoring is a good fit for IoT monitoring with the concept of custom metrics for the "global" resource and device id as a label. according to https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#stackdriver_monitoring_services

the limits are
    500 time series per chargeable resource, plus 250 metric types per project.

does every different value of the label count as a time series? is "global" a chargeable resource? does it mean that i'll only be able to monitor 500 devices with a single custom metric with this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, every unique label value creates a new timeseries, i.e. a unique line on a graph.

There are two types of labels - monitored resource labels and metric labels. Whereas the resource labels uniquely identify the resource being monitored, the metric labels are auxiliary information by which to break-down or group-by/aggregate the metric data. The cardinality of both types of label values contribute to the total number of timeseries in use.

The "global" monitored resource is not a chargeable resource, i.e. you don't get charged $N/resource. Chargeable resources are listed in https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#chargeable-resources.

If you have 100 chargeable resources in a given hour, you get an allotment of 500*100 = 50K timeseries for user-defined custom metrics. The allotment is shared for all custom metrics. The number of timeseries exceeding the allotment in that hour is the "time series overage" which has a separate cost per timeseries as listed in https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#metric-allotments.

As noted in the pricing page, allotment limits and overage charges for user-defined metrics is currently not effective (postponed until further notice).

Also note that pricing is subject to change in the future.

Comment: So if I have a single custom metric with a device_id label and its reported for the "global" resource, I can have 100k devices which is limited by the project limit for 100k time series? What will be the pricing in this case?

Comment: Before I answer your question: (1) Creating 100K time series using a metric label with the `global` resource type is not recommended due to high cardinality (2) 100K time series is also the max quota limit for number of active time series (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quotas). For a hypothetical scenario to understand the not-yet-effective billing model, the usage of 100K time series with say 100 chargeable resources would cost $0.10 x (100K- (100*500)) = $5K. Again, pricing is subject to change before its effective.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the reason i'm asking about the global resource is that you can't create new resources..